# Undefined Offset 1, but count() == 2

Tags: php, sql

I have an array which is populated by an sql query. I expect two elements, and the count() function returns 2. I can access the first element without issue, but when I try to access the element at index 1, I get the error "Undefined offset 1". Here is how the array is populated:

```
function getThreadsByOwner($owner_id,$mysqli)
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT thread_id 
                              FROM threads
                              WHERE owner_id = ?
                              ORDER BY time ASC");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $owner_id);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {header("Location:server_error.php");}
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_array();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's causing this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that `fetch_array()` only returns the data from one row - and the different elements don't symbolize rows, but columns. See https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

So the reason, why Index 1 is undefined is, because you're only fetching one column.

If you want both rows, you have to call the command twice.

This should solve your problem:

```
$ret = [];
$ret[0] = $result->fetch_array();
$ret[1] = $result->fetch_array();
return $ret;
```

However, it's also possible that your tables are empty, and that there are less than 2 rows in your result-set. You should also care about that, and use:

```
$ret = [];
$row = $result->fetch_array();
if($row != NULL){
     $ret[0] = $row;
     $row = $result->fetch_array();
     if($row != NULL){
         $ret[1] = $row;
    }
}
return $ret;
```

Now you also have to care about smaller Arrays, when you try to access them.
You can use `count($ret)` for that, which should always return 0, 1 or 2.

As long as you only want to read 2 rows, this code is OK. But as soon as you retrieve several rows at once, a loop is the better (and more readable) alternative:

```
$ret = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $ret[] = $row;
}
return $ret;
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes perfect sense. I should have read the documentation instead of just assuming. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

fetch_array() only returns one row.

You need to do use it in a while loop:

```
function getThreadsByOwner($owner_id,$mysqli)
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT thread_id 
                              FROM threads
                              WHERE owner_id = ?
                              ORDER BY time ASC");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $owner_id);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {header("Location:server_error.php");}
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $res = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $res[] = $row;
    }
    
    return $res;
}
```

This will return an array with any amount of rows, not just 2.

[Link to documentation](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array)

Hope this helps!